while translating the text/documents from one language to another language using google cloud,can we pass locale instead of language code?
while translating the text/documents from one language to another language using google cloud translation API, is there any chance to pass target locale or only target language code, because with the locale code, we will get more accuracy when compared to target language code
for example we have a course in English language (language code: en) , locale : English (United States) (locale code: en-us), if we want to translate to Spanish (Mexico) (es-mx), I know that only by giving target language code i.e es is fine till now, but is there any chance to pass the target locale code es-mx or not, please confirm
why am asking is incase of video/audio files translation we are passing the locale code as input for accuracy (i.e not passing language code)
thanks & Regards,
Ganesh P
please give me by providing the solution.
